# NVD3 chart controls don't work when hooking mouse events on svg elements

Tags: javascript, svg, nvd3.js

I have an area chart in nvd3:

```
var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
    .x(function (d) { return d[0] })
    .y(function (d) { return Math.round(d[1]) })
    .clipEdge(true)
    .showControls(true)
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true);
```

As you can see, I have enabled showControls, which displays three small buttons (Stacked, Stream and Expanded) in the top left corner of the chart.

Since it was desired to select subsections of the chart by dragging the mouse over, I implemented the following solution by hooking up mouseup, mousedown and mousemove events on the SVG element that contains the chart.

```
    var mouseDown = false;
    var mouseDownCoords;
    var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 0).attr("height", 0)
        .attr("fill", "rgba(43,48,87,0.3)");

    svg.on('mousedown', function () {
        var height = svg[0][0].height;

        mouseDownCoords = d3.mouse(this);
        mouseDown = true;

        rect.attr("x", mouseDownCoords[0]);
        rect.attr("height", height.animVal.value);

        // Register mousemove when the mouse button is down
        svg.on('mousemove', function () {
            var coords = d3.mouse(this);
            rect.attr("width", Math.max(coords[0] - mouseDownCoords[0], 0));
        });
    });

    svg.on('mouseup', function () {
        if (mouseDown) {
            var coords = d3.mouse(this);
            var width = Math.max(coords[0] - mouseDownCoords[0], 0);

            mouseDown = false;
            rect.attr("width", 0);

            if (width > 0) {
                var totalWidth = svg[0][0].width.animVal.value;
                var totalPeriod = dateTo.getTime() - dateFrom.getTime();
                var newDateFrom = new Date(Math.floor(dateFrom.getTime() + totalPeriod * mouseDownCoords[0] / totalWidth));
                var newDateTo = new Date(Math.floor(newDateFrom.getTime() + totalPeriod * width / totalWidth));
                window.setSearchTimeframe(newDateFrom, newDateTo);
            }
        }

        // Unregister mousemove
        svg.on('mousemove', null);
    });
```

However, registering these event callbacks stops the control buttons from working. When I click on them, nothing happens, even if the pointer correctly changes when I hover them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, registering events on elements outside NVD3's built-in event system really seems to destroy things internally (which shouldn't be the case, in my opinion). You could work around this by positioning an invisible element over the part of the chart that needs custom behaviour.

### Demo

The red rectangle is the part of the chart with custom behaviour (click it).

```js
var chartElement = d3.select("#chart svg");
var chart;

nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.label
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.value
    })
    .showLabels(true);

  var chartData = [{
    label: "Foo",
    value: 67
  }, {
    label: "Bar",
    value: 33
  }];

  chartElement
    .datum(chartData)
    .call(chart);

  $("#customUI").on("mousedown", function() {
    alert("Some custom behaviour...");
  });

  return chart;
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#chart {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
}
#customUI {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
}
#customUI:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="chart">
    <svg>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="customUI">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround but there's a problem. Having an hidden overlay on the chart will prevent mouse events from going through and I have additional behaviours based on these: for example, when you move the cursor on an area, a tooltip shows the number of items on the current x value. I could move the invisible wrapper on the bottom of the x axis but that would limit usability. I really wish there could be a way to fix nvd3 events directly.

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty flawed approach. Maybe you should create an issue here (if you haven't already): https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues